# Using Windows 8 Tablet As Slave

Tags: windows-8, active-directory, windows-runtime, master-slave, windows-store

i'm working on Windows 8 application, that will be used for students in intranet to take quiz. For this application, when tablets thats connected to network, for example receive some command from server machine, the quiz application will start in all tablets at same time.

during quiz i dont want students to have access to internet nor desktop resources. They wont be able to pass to desktop to get hints from documents etc during quiz.

It can be either if possible WinRT application, or traditional Windows application. How can i achive this, i will be happy if you can guide me on this.

Mainly, during lesson, teacher will be able to control students machine remotely from his laptop or tablet.

Comment: This is a system administration question. You should not have any ability to control this just from an app. Do you own these devices? Did you assign the devices to students?

Comment: There is a demand for that, There is a smart board in each class which runs windows 7. Teacher either will use this pc or a tablet to control student tablets. How the student tablets can be configured to listen commands and when it receive certain command, a  program will work and prevent any other thing to focus.

Comment: Who owns the tablets? You are jumping steps straight from requirements to deliverable.

Comment: School owns tablets. School buys lets say 100 tablet and gives to students at the beginning of semester. School want to have full control on tablets during lessons, including making quizzes in class.

Comment: Look up group policy update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298444 Windows 8 has new (and better) tools to deal with issues like this. Sorry I don't have a better answer. Please come back and answer your own question when you have solved this issue?